# Emberjs, {{#link-to}} Handlebars break when wrapped around DOM elements

Tags: html, ember.js, link-to, handlebars.js, nest

I need to create a {{linkTo}} that wraps around an entire table-row, but it does not allow me to use {{linkTo}} if there are any non-ember DOM elements in between {{#linkTo}} and {{/linkTo}}

When I put linkTo directly around {{Name}} , like in the code below, it works

```
{{#each}}
  <tr class="people-list">
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" class="toggle">           
      <label class="category-text">
        {{#linkTo 'category' this}}
          {{Name}}
        {{/linkTo}}
      </label>
      <img class="table-img" src="images/x.png">
      <img class="table-img" {{action 'edit'}} src="images/pencil-grey.png">
      {{/linkTo}
    </td>
  </tr>
{{/each}}
```

but when I try to extend those links to outside of the , like shown below, the linkTo doesn't work at all.

```
{{#each}}
{{#linkTo 'category' this}}
  <tr class="people-list">
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" class="toggle">            
      <label class="category-text">       
          {{Name}}
      </label>
      <img class="table-img" src="images/x.png">
      <img class="table-img" {{action 'edit'}} src="images/pencil-grey.png">
    </td>
  </tr>
{{/linkTo}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Wrapping the `tr` elements in an anchor link would be invalid HTML.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using {{#linkTo}}, you can get this result by calling an action which redirects to a different route:

```
{{#each}}
  <tr class="people-list" {{action 'goTo' this}}>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" class="toggle">            
      <label class="category-text">       
          {{Name}}
      </label>
      <img class="table-img" src="images/x.png">
      <img class="table-img" {{action 'edit'}} src="images/pencil-grey.png">
    </td>
  </tr>
{{/each}}
```

And then on your controller:

```
actions: {
    goTo : function(input){
        this.transitionToRoute('category', input);
    }
}
```

Comment: I actually prefer this way

Comment: Something to note about this way: you won't get the `active` class that you would get if you used `link-to` if the "link" is still on screen when you enter the single category route.

Comment: @Jason How would not having the `active` class become a problem? I have a dynamic template that i `{{render 'globalList' model}}` inside the template of all other models (ex. `category.hbs`, `user.hbs`, etc.), but when I use the `goTo` action in this particular circumstance, i get the an error

Answer (score 1):

why don't you use a view with tagName='tr', and in the click event redirect to the route you want ? something like this:

```
App.LinkToCategory = Ember.View.extend({
  classNames: ['people-list'],
  tagName: 'tr',
  click: function() {
    router.transitionTo('category', category)
  }
})
```

and in your template something like this:

```
{{#view App.LinkToCategory category=this}}
  <td>
    <input type="checkbox" class="toggle">            
    <label class="category-text">       
      {{Name}}
    </label>
    <img class="table-img" src="images/x.png">
    <img class="table-img" {{action 'edit'}} src="images/pencil-grey.png">
  </td>
{{/view}}
```

I didn't check if it works, but you got the idea.

Answer (score 0):

The `link-to` helper accepts a `tagName` property, so you can make the element that does the linking the `tr` itself.

```
{{#each}}
  {{#linkTo "category" this tagName="tr" class="people-list" role="link"}}
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" class="toggle">            
      <label class="category-text">       
          {{Name}}
      </label>
      <img class="table-img" src="images/x.png">
      <img class="table-img" {{action "edit" bubbles=false}} src="images/pencil-grey.png">
    </td>
  {{/linkTo}
{{/each}}
```

You may also need to add `bubbles=false` to your edit button, so that clicking it doesn't follow the link. And because the "link" is not an `a` element, I've also added the `role="link"` attribute so it is accessible to screen readers.